# Friend has access to friend's member, but can't seem to update friend's member

Tags: c++, constructor, friend, deque

Within the Dealer class, I declare Player as a friend class. Note that deck is a Dealer member, and I have the following Dealer function:

```
deque<pair<int, string>> Dealer::deal(int numOfCards){
    deque<pair<int, string>> dealtCards;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfCards; i++)
    {       
        dealtCards.push_back(deck.front());
        deck.pop_front(); // once a card is dealt, delete it from the deck
    }

    return(dealtCards);
}
```

When I call this function directly, for example in main(), the deck is updated appropriately (front cards are deleted). However, when I call this function from the Player class, the Dealer deck member is not updated. For example, I'm expecting this function to update Dealer deck, but it's not:

```
Player::Player(Dealer dealer, int numOfCards){// deal numOfCards to player
    holeCards = dealer.deal(numOfCards);
}
```

I don't see what's the difference. Player *does* have access to Dealer's private member deck, as I can see the holeCards are updated correctly. But for some reason, this constructor is just not performing the pop_front() portion of the deal function. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: `Dealer dealer` in your parameters: you're passing a _copy_ of a dealer to your constructor. That's probably not what you meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Player::Player(Dealer dealer, int numOfCards)
```

to

```
Player::Player(Dealer &dealer, int numOfCards)
```

If you want to understand more check [swap by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399217/c-pass-by-reference-program) example.